# Write video stream from camera into file using VLC

Tags: video, vlc, video-encoding, libvlc

I'm using VLC wrapper VLC.DotNet, libvlc 3.0.3 or 3.0.4 nightly and I try example:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var currentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
        // Default installation path of VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows
        var libDirectory =
            new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "libvlc", IntPtr.Size == 4 ? "win-x86" : "win-x64"));

        var destination = Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "record.mp4");

        using (var mediaPlayer = new Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcMediaPlayer(libDirectory))
        {

            var mediaOptions = new[]
            {
                ":sout=file{dst=" + destination + "}",
                ":sout-keep"
            };

            mediaPlayer.SetMedia(new Uri("rtsp://192.168.x.xxx/ch1.h264"),
                mediaOptions);

            mediaPlayer.Play();

            Console.WriteLine($"Recording in {destination}");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Everything works great I see recorded file in folder, but when I change media options format, file not recording...
F.E:

```
 var mediaOptions = new[]
        {
            ":sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264}:std{access=file,mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv}),file{dst=" + destination + "}",
            ":sout-keep"
        };
```

Log screenshot:
[image]

I need to encode streaming video from camera into H.264 mp4 video file with mp3 or AAC audio.
It would be great if anyone help me with this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my media options to:

```
var lowQualityMediaOptions = new[]
        {
            ":sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,width=640,height=480,canvas-width=640,canvas-height=480,fps=4}:std{access=file,mux=ts,dst=" + lowQualityDestination + "}",
            ":sout-all"
        };
```

And everything works good.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I'm very late.
I was facing the same issue, after a long long research, it seems VLC subcommands work by using '', so I resolved this issue like this:

```
vlcControl1.SetMedia(new Uri(YourUrl), new string[] { ":sout=#duplicate{dst='transcode{vcodec=h264,width=640,height=480,fps=20}:std{access=file,mux=ts,dst=YourDestinationPath}',dst=display}" });
```

After that, I could preview stream video while recording.

See the documentation here: https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Modules/display/

Regards.